# MySQL starting error (Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such fie or directory)

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble starting `mysql` and `mysqld`.

Output of `sudo service mysql start` command is `mysql : Unrecognized service`

Same way output of `sudo service mysqld start` is nothing

When I tried `sudo service mysqld status` it says `stopped`

Note: I'm using rhel 6.5
MySQL version is mysqld  Ver 5.6.21-ndb-7.3.7-cluster-gpl for linux-glibc2.5 on x86_64 (MySQL Cluster Community Server (GPL))

I went through `/var/log/mysql.log` found this error :

```
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1600607
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't create/write to fie '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2015-10-20 08:00:54 23694 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such fie or directory
151020 08:00:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

For which I looked online and tried to fix issue which said to be of the permission, So I created to fix this error which `/var/run/mysqld` for `mysql.pid` and I did `chown` the directory to `mysql:mysql`

But still the problem persist.
Can anyone help me out with this!

Thanks

Permissions of data directory `/var/lib/mysql` :

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql root      4096 Oct 20 08:00 .
drwxr-xr-x. 33 root  root      4096 Oct 20 08:00 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 mysql mysql       56 Oct 20 08:00 auto.cnf
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 mysql mysql 12582912 Oct 20 08:00 ibdata1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 mysql mysql 50331648 Oct 20 08:00 ib_logfile0
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 mysql mysql 50331648 Oct 20 08:00 ib_logfile1
srwxr-xr-x.  1 mysql mysql        0 Oct 20 08:00 mysql.sock
```

Output for `ps aux | grep mysql` :

```
ec2-user 19246  0.0  0.0 103256   832 pts/2    S+   16:39   0:00 grep mysql
ec2-user 31724  0.0  0.0 127088  3740 pts/0    S+   Jan22   0:00 mysql -u root -p
```

Output for `sudo rpm -qa | egrep -i mysql`

```
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.6.27-2.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: @BK435 Updated question! please check.

Comment: are these the permissions of  /var/run/mysqld/ ?

Comment: root owns the permission for parent directory! @BK435

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 2 mysql root 4096 Oct 20 08:00 /var/lib/mysql @BK435

Comment: @BK435 I've changed it, still does not work! Any other suggestion? Error logs show the same thing.

Comment: @BK435 Actually it dint create any folder! I manually made a directory and  chown it to 'mysql:mysql' already but still the same thing. When I restart the services it shows error 'mysql: unrecognized service'!

Comment: I did it! but it is still not creating the folder mysqld in /var/run and I did everything through root.
I'm using rhel 6.5! @BK435 I have update question with the output of ps auz command! please check

Comment: I have posted result of the command in question above please check!

Comment: My mistake messed up a little, here is the output for it :
` ps aux | mysql`
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`  @BK435

Comment: @BK435 I did the same before! I dont know what command was that as the comment was deleted. here is the result for the command BTW these may be some processes already running in background.  `ec2-user 19246  0.0  0.0 103256   832 pts/2    S+   16:39   0:00 grep mysql
ec2-user 31724  0.0  0.0 127088  3740 pts/0    S+   Jan22   0:00 mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Yeah any other solution you would suggest? @BK435

Comment: @BK435 mysqld  Ver 5.6.21-ndb-7.3.7-cluster-gpl for linux-glibc2.5 on x86_64 (MySQL Cluster Community Server (GPL))

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/mysql /usr/local/old.mysql
sudo yum install mysql-server mysql
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo chkconfig mysqld on
sudo service mysqld start
```

Comment: `sudo mysql_install_db` does not work I'm using rhel 6.5

Comment: @BK435 Its mysqld  Ver 5.6.21-ndb-7.3.7-cluster-gpl for linux-glibc2.5 on x86_64 (MySQL Cluster Community Server (GPL))

Comment: I see you have /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld , which indicates you tried to install it manually, probably from source. That's a bad idea.

Comment: Updated my response.

Comment: Is there any way I can retain my data which I have on my mysql data folder? Do you have any reference which mentions how to do it?@Eduardo

Comment: Run: "rpm -qa | egrep -i mysql\|maria"

And let us know the output.

Comment: I've updated the question with output of rpm command. please check!  @Eduardo

Comment: It doesn't look like your /var/lib/mysql has any database. Each database would have its own directory in there. e.g.: /var/lib/mysql/mydatabase/

So, if you believe you have MySQL databases in this server, run: find / -name ibdata1 or find / -type d -name yourdbname  (if you remember the database name).